# cakephp's model save method doesnt work

Tags: php, cakephp

Hi when I want to save changes to my model through `edit()` method of controller the following error happens:

```
Error: Call to a member function save() on a non-object
File: K:\xampp\xampp\htdocs\app\Controller\UsersController.php
Line: 39
```

this is the method:

```
    public function edit($id = null){
        $this->User->id = $id;
        if(!$this->User->exists()){
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
        }
        if($this->request->is('post')){
            ###### line number 39 - Where error happens >>>> 
            if($this->Uesr->save($this->request->data)){
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }else{
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again'));
            }
        }else{
            $this->request->data = $this->User->read(null, $id);
            unset($this->request->data['User']['password']);
        }
    }
```

but when I call to this object within `add()` method there is no error, This is the code for `add()` method:

```
    public function add(){
        if($this->request->is('post')){
            $this->User->create();
            if($this->User->save($this->request->data)){
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved.'));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }else{
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again'));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You've spelt the model name as 'Uesr' on the line that the error is happening. Is this your problem?

Comment: @MustafaShujaie Double check that syntax, where did you initiate a `Uesr` model? Please not that the s and e are switched: `User` -> `Uesr`. Looks like a typo to me.

Comment: oh, OMG. I am really silly sorry guys and thanks @Josh and Oldskool

Answer (score 1):

You have a spelling mistake in name of the controller in the edit action.

Use:

```
$this->User->save($this->request->data)
```

instead of:

```
$this->Uesr->save($this->request->data)
```